# Button tabs with images in delphi

Tags: delphi, tabs

I would like to dvelop an app with a GUI like CCleaner, where you have a left aligned tabs, (but not the typically wicvh contain only a word) with an image in a button.
I couldn't find the properties, probably because i'm working only with the installation of delphi XE2, an i have only the TTabControl on the win32 pallete.
i don't know how to create a form like this i call above. Can it be created with a ttabcontrol?
Could anyone help me? I want a form with a left tab with button in each option, that change the right side of the form...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is. Can you ask something a little more specific than "could anyone help me"?

Comment: I'm not aware of any component that would be similar to TTabControl but have its tab on sides instead on top. But you can achieve similar results by using frames for right side and any custom controls for left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Win32 palette there are `TTabControl` (as you know) and `TPageControl` which is similar to `TTabControl` but has separate pages (called `TTabSheet`) for each tab.

Both have a property `TabPosition` with 4 possible values: `tpTop` (default), `tpBottom`, `tpLeft` and `tpRight`. The text of the tabs are vertical for tab positions `tpLeft` and `tpRight`. Both tab controls also supports images in the tabs through the `Images` property which can take a `TImageList` as container for the images.

If you don't like the vertical text on the tabs, you can compose your form with separate buttons on the left and panels or frames as pages. As buttons you can use `TBitBtn` or `TButton` buttons placed directly on the form or on a panel if you like, or you can use a `TButtonGroup` All of these supports the `TImageList` mentioned above. For some you can have separate images for disabled, hovered (hot), selected and pressed states.

Read more about these controls in the help.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your coments. I add a TButtonGroup, and i add it 4 items which are obviously buttons..but those appear horizontally not vertically as you show me. Or you recommend me a TPanel with BitBtn?

Comment: @user3780282 You are welcome. The `TButtonGroup` has a property `ButtonOptions` with a subproperty `gboFullSize` which you can set to `True`. Alternatively you can set the `ButtonWidth` property of the `TButtonGroup` to a value that forces the buttons vertically.

Comment: then i have to intercept de onclick event..how to change the Panel on the right? i will need one frame to each button?

Comment: Yes, change frames in `OnClick` of buttons. Instead of frames or panels (which can become tricky at design time) you can use a `TPageControl` with hidden tabs. For each `TTabSheet` set its `TabVisible` to `False`. Change tabsheet at run time and design time by changing the `ActivePage` property of the `TPageControl`.